# About a (so very) strong version of flatness

Tags: modules, abelian-categories

Let $A, B$  rings. WHat are $(A, B)$-bimodule  $M$ such that $(-)\otimes_A M: Mod_A \to Mod_B$ preserve all (small) limits?

A second question is: the characterization  of bimodule ${}_AM_B$ such that  as morphism  $M: A \to B$ in the  bicategory of bimodules,  they have a  left adjoint.